# Qt versus Qt4 (versioning in tags?)

Tags: discussion, tags

The [Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) and [Qt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt4) tags could better be merged I think (same for [PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyqt) and [PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyqt4)).

Qt4 has been out since 2005.

Or do we want this pluralism for when Qt5, Qt6 comes out in a few years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to make sure that `[Qt]` tagged questions aren't without a doubt Qt3 related.

Also, Qt is generally referred to as Qt4, so I don't see the problem with the tag. We call IE 8 `[IE8]`.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, I'd be for keeping the numbers. Qt gets a whole lot of new features even with every *minor* release, and tends to deprecate APIs and break backwards compatibility quite a bit with major releases (they did with 3 -> 4, anyway). So we can be pretty sure that many of today's Qt(4) questions will be totally outdated in two years. I think it's good if the version numbers reflect that.

Comment: Is a Qt5 planned? http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-02/thread01608-0.html

Comment: @voyager: If it's not, the OP is the last lion roaring at the last dusty fountain. Either way...

Comment: @voyager, @balpha: Why would there **not** be a Qt5? Qt 4.4, 4.5 and 4.6 got released at a stable pace (Qt 4.7 technology preview is out now: http://ow.ly/16O9xT).